# iPhone: Hide/Show controls under response

Tags: iphone

I am trying to show and hide three controls like UIBUtton, UILabel etc. in some scenario. I am doing this using below two functions.

```
- (void) hide
{
    usernameField.hidden=YES;
    passwordField.hidden=YES;
    myLabel.hidden=YES;    
}

- (void) show
{
    usernameFieldField.hidden=NO;
    passwordField.hidden=NO;
    myLabel.hidden=NO;
}
```

But, when i call these functions under some server response code, that is i'm trying to show under connectionDidFinishLoading in success/failure server response..Its not doing that. i.e. Its not showing or hiding these controls in these situations..But same time, if i call these functions under a button click, its showing/hiding controls..So, Would these functions be called only under some events like button click? Can't we call from anywhere like i'm trying to do?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your connectionDidFinishLoading

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show)
                    withObject:nil
                  waitUntilDone:wait];
```

the reason is UI update show be called on main thread in order to get redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the hidden state of a control will not immediately draw the change to the screen, they will only flag it as needing to be drawn at some point in the future.

If the main thread is busy, then they will not get a chance to draw themselves.

Is your NSURLConnection code running on the main thread? You should move it to a background thread (but beware, changing the hidden property must be done on the main thread, not on a background thread! Look up grand central dispatch.)